# Panoramic lens weird gap between objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fisheye

I encountered this problem when I tried to use the Fisheye lens. There is no gap between the ground and the object

[image]

but when I switch the render engine to the Cycles render view this gap appears.

[image]

Here are my camera settings.

[image]

There is no animation in the scene. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check displacement in the shader graph

Comment: I agree with Allen - A displacement texture in Cycles is essentially a vertex shader - the vertices of the object move in accordance with the values provided by the displacement texture - if the displacement texture is only one uniform color (grayscale), or the object (floor plane) is insufficiently subdivided, the whole plane will "move" to some Z-axis location based on the values provided, relative to the midlevel. You will not see this affect in Solid or Material Preview modes (or rendered preview using EEVEE).